# Plastering: Solutions to a cornice that has fallen off

Tags: plaster

I went into a room today and saw that this had happened to the cornice.

[image: Plaster fallen]

I have no plastering experience but some general DIY experience. Is it feasible to plaster it oneself, and if so what tools should I use?

I am also interested to know what would cause this sort of thing to happen. Is there a risk that it could happen again?

What would happen if I just left that area unplastered for 4 months? The reason I ask is that this house is being renovated in 4 months anyway, and so it would be convenient if I could leave things until then.

Comment: I usually nail them in place and only need to fill the joints and nail holes. This can be done DIY. My personal preference is to use a brad nailer with 16/18 gauge as long as my gun will shoot to get the best holding power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would happen if I just left that area unplastered for 4 months?

It would look exactly like it does in your photo, i.e. a bit ugly.

You could paint the exposed orange plaster to make it slightly less ugly.

> Is it feasible to plaster it oneself, and if so what tools should I use?

Just take the cornice off the floor and reattach it with high strength grab adhesive and/or with nails. 5 minutes and done, and it looks less ugly than currently.

Depending on where your personal balance is for effort/ugliness you can either leave it like that, or try and use filler to hide the nail holes and sort out where the corners meet (they're never perfect) / make good the bashed corner.

Or you might even want to go and buy a new piece of the cornice which doesn't have a bashed corner, and mitre it to fit etc. But given you're considering just leaving it without doing anything at all, this is probably more effort than you'll find worth it.